# Windows 10: Taskbar will be in front of fullscreen games

Tags: pc, windows-10

I will start any video games. They are almost always in fullscreen or windowed fullscreen. Mostly later because I can alt+tab and look up meta-game info when necessary.

Ever since the windows 10 update like 3 or 4 weeks ago. I don't remember exactly when.

The problem started and there seem to be no sure fire way to fix this. Restart might resolve the issue for a little while before coming back. Alt+tab just move the window down and right as expect then back to the same issue again.

I can't be 100% sure where the cause is. But I strongly suspect it has to do with my old PC and how it interact with windows 10/current nvidia driver.

Now the issue is that the windows task bar that normally would disappear if I have a fullscreen application running will NOT hide. Instead it will treat the taskbar as click for taskbar instead of the fullscreen. It also block some button/info on the bottom which makes it impossible to play certain games that may depend on the area behind the task bar.

Here is an example screenshot from Dawn of War 3. IGNORE the low quality graphic I was just testing the tutorial and see if it runs at all.

[image: Example of taskbar being in front]

That said there are plenty of games that will not suffer from it at all while other do.

My setup is black 1075t amd cpu.
Nvidia 660 GTX.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the task bar and selecting auto hide? That might be a temporary fix at least

Comment: Yes that fix the "blocking" view. But it will show up as soon you try to hover over icon close to that edge. It is problematic if I try to reach those icon in the bottom right in that same screen shot. By problematic I mean that it will show itself up and block the clicks if I so much try to move there too quickly.

Comment: Have you ended the windows explorer process and restarted it?

Comment: Yes I already tried. That temporarily fix it until the task bar finish loading and come back in front of the application again.

Comment: This happens for full screen video playback as well for me. I fixed it by disabling aero from steps here. [Disable Aero, Aero Peek](https://superuser.com/questions/1056921/how-can-i-completely-disable-aero-peek)

Comment: Try pressing `Alt` + `Enter` when a game is loaded to force fullscreen. Please note that not all games recognize this command so results may vary.

Comment: I have this happen to me too, but usually I just have to click away from the game, and then click back into it.

Answer (score 34):

1) Open the task manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc)

2) Select "Windows Explorer"

3) Click the "Restart" button in the bottom right corner of the task manager windows

Comment: Then it's behind games, even when they're in the background. This has been the case ever since creators update and is really annoying.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it permanently instead of having to repeat this all the time?

Answer (score 3):

I used two simple options to hide windows task bar:

First one is to tap twice Win button on keyboard. It would call and then hide Start menu, which at same time would hide task bar.

Second one is to have other application window open on same monitor and use alt-tab to swap to it and back to full screen application.

P.S. Surprisingly non of above worked for me right now, but it still can be useful.

Comment: Win+Win worked for me, Restart or Alt+Tab didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Go to taskbar settings and change the taskbar position. It instantly fixes it, and you can even put it back down if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Some people claim that unpinning all the taskbar icons and then pinning them back fixes the issue.

Comment: I say "some people", because I haven't had this issue myself. I was looking the issue up though and this was suggested as a solution and a bunch of people replied that it worked for them and I didn't see anyone say that it didn't. [Source](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/61190-how-do-i-disable-always-top-taskbar-2.html#post889165)

Answer (score 0):

Right cliock on the desired app, click properties.
Go to compatibilty tab.
check Disable full screen optimization.
this worked for me for an app,the app still runs in full screen.

Answer (score -3):

1. Right-click the taskbar
2. select 'taskbar settingts'
3. enable "automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode'